# Inject strongly typed instance with structuremap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have this IPageModel interface which is the base for all my models in my project.
The current model is a part of the RouteData and I want to inject this instance to my controllers.

this is how I do it today

```
x.For<IPageModel>().UseSpecial(y => y.ConstructedBy( r => ((MvcHandler) HttpContext.Current.Handler).RequestContext.RouteData.GetCurrentModel<IPageModel>(‌​)));
```

Is it possible to tell structuremap to inject the correct type instead of the IPageModel?

An couple examples would be like this:

```
public HomeController(Home model) {
// Home implements IPageModel
}
```

and

```
public PageController(Page model) {
// Page implements IPageModel
}
```

The RouteData object has the correct instance of the model

Comment: Are you resolving your controllers through structuremap as well?

Comment: @thekip Yes, I'm using the IDependencyResolver interface like this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/elee/archive/2010/11/19/asp-net-mvc-3-idependencyresolver-and-structuremap.aspx

Comment: What benefit do you gain by injecting the model into your controller constructor?

Comment: @joshua-flanagan I think one benefit is that my controllers is more testable.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your controllers generic, so they work with a specific type of IPageModel.

so you would have
`HomeController<Home>` and
`PageController<Page>`

If you make them derive from a single base class which only has a constructor with 1 parameter (an instance of T) so:

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> where T : IPageModel  
{  
    protected T Model { get; private set; }  

    public BaseController(T model)  
    {  
        Model = model;  
    }
```

This way you will get a controller with a newly constructed instance of (for example) Home. I don't think you want an empty model but you'll have to handle this in your registrations in structuremap by scoping them on the session or request for example.